# Running Spring Hibernate Project in Tomcat as Standalone and Embedded Tomcat in STS IDE

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have an issue when i run my application as a standalone web application using Tomcat.

I use spring , struts 2 and hibernate .

The weird part is when i run the application from the embedded tomcat in my STS IDE it is running fine.

In both scenarios the web application runs fine but certain hibernate models are not getting initialized causing certain screens to fail when the application is run in the stand alone mode.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the exact error:

Error in Pre-loading models or ppa_ids
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: RealTimeModel is not mapped [select distinct forecast_model from RealTimeModel]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: RealTimeModel is not mapped [select distinct forecast_model from RealTimeModel]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:656)

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<!-- MyBatis setup start -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="insert*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"></property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="permissionMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.guzmanenergy.dal.PermissionMapper"></property>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="roleMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.guzmanenergy.dal.RoleMapper"></property>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="userMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.guzmanenergy.dal.UserMapper"></property>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="authorityMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.guzmanenergy.dal.AuthorityMapper"></property>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="permissionService" class="com.guzmanenergy.service.impl.PermissionServiceImpl">
    <property name="permissionMapper" ref="permissionMapper"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="authorityService" class="com.guzmanenergy.service.impl.AuthorityServiceImpl">
    <property name="authorityMapper" ref="authorityMapper"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="userServiceTarget" class="com.guzmanenergy.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="usermapper" ref="userMapper"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="userService" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target" ref="userServiceTarget"></property>
</bean>
<!-- MyBatis setup stop -->
<!-- email setup start -->
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <!-- 25, 465, 587 -->
    <property name="username" value="support@getrident.com" />
    <property name="password" value="Aragon101!" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<!--    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"> -->
<!--        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" /> -->
<!--        <property name="port" value="587" />  25, 465, 587 -->
<!--        <property name="username" value="GPMreporting@gmail.com" /> -->
<!--        <property name="password" value="Guzman1234" /> -->
<!--        <property name="javaMailProperties"> -->
<!--           <props> -->
<!--                  <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop> -->
<!--                  <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop> -->
<!--           </props> -->
<!--        </property> -->
<!--    </bean> -->
<bean id="resetPasswordMailer" class="com.guzmanenergy.util.ResetPasswordMailer">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
<bean id="sendEmail" class="com.guzmanenergy.util.SendMail">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
<!-- email setup stop -->
<!-- Spring + Hibernate Configuration -->
<import resource="applicationContext-hibernate.xml"/>
<!-- Curve Action Beans -->
<bean id="curveDao" class="com.guzmanenergy.action.dao.Impl.CurveDaoImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="Hibernate_sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="curveService" class="com.guzmanenergy.action.service.Impl.CurveServiceImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="curveDao">
        <ref bean="curveDao"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="curveAction" class="com.guzmanenergy.action.CurveAction_s2sh" scope="prototype">
    <property name="curveService">
        <ref bean="curveService"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Curve Action Beans End -->
<!-- Beans for physical_longterm_main -->
<bean id="physicalLongtermMainDao" class="com.guzmanenergy.action.dao.Impl.PhysicalLongtermMainDaoImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="Hibernate_sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Beans for physical_longterm_main  End-->
<!-- Real Time Model Beans -->
<bean id="realTimeModelDao" class="com.guzmanenergy.action.dao.Impl.RealTimeModelDaoImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="Hibernate_sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="realTimeModelService" class="com.guzmanenergy.action.service.Impl.RealTimeModelServiceImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="realTimeModelDao">
        <ref bean="realTimeModelDao"/>
    </property>
    <property name="physicalLongtermMainDao">
        <ref bean="physicalLongtermMainDao"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="RealTimeModelAction" class="com.guzmanenergy.action.RealTime_Model_Action" scope="prototype">
    <property name="realTimeModelService">
        <ref bean="realTimeModelService"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Real Time Model Beans -->
<!-- forecast model download -->
<bean id="ForcastModelDownloadAction" class="com.guzmanenergy.action.ForcastModelDownloadAction" scope="prototype">
    <property name="realTimeModelService">
        <ref bean="realTimeModelService"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- forecast model download -->
<!-- Spring + Hibernate Configuration End -->
```

applicationContext-hibernate.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" id="ETRM_database">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
 -->

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="Hibernate_sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:com/guzmanenergy/action/domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/ehcache.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <!--
    <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property> 
     -->
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" scope="prototype">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="Hibernate_sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="ETRM_tx" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.guzmanenergy.action.service.Impl.*.*(..))" id="ETRM_perform"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="ETRM_tx" pointcut-ref="ETRM_perform"/>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: This suggests that the query syntax might be the problem:
[Hibernate table not mapped error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446048/hibernate-table-not-mapped-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer , the hbm.xml files were in the main/java folder. but they ought to be in the main/resources folder.